# Writing an InputStream to a File in Java

Tags: java, file, stream, inputstream, filewriter

I am writing this method which will convert an InputStream into a file, but the method is working for some of the inputs but not for all  (when i pass a zip file as an InputStream it works). It simply creates a file with 0 bytes.

I know that this question has been asked before, before anyone mark it as duplicate please go through what i have done so far..

This is what I have tried so far. Most of these solutions are found from StackOverFlow.

```java
private void saveFile(String filename, InputStream input) throws IOException 
{
        if (filename == null) {
            return;
        }


        File file = new File(filename);


        //*************** 1st *****************

        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("This is inputStream:"+stringFromInputStream);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, StringFromInputStream);


        //********************2nd **********************
        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        byte[] aByte = StringFromInputStream.getBytes();
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.write(aByte, fos);


        //*******************3rd**********************
        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        byte[] aByte = StringFromInputStream.getBytes();
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(aByte);


        //*********************4th*********************
        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        FileWriter fr=new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(fr);
        br.write(StringFromInputStream);
        br.flush();
        fr.flush();
        br.close();
        fr.close();



        //*************5th**********************
        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        Files.write(Paths.get(filename), StringFromInputStream.getBytes());


        //************************6th**************
        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, StringFromInputStream);


        //******************7th*********************
        String stringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(input, "UTF-8");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        printWriter.print(StringFromInputStream);
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();


        //**********************8th*************************
        final Path destination = Paths.get(filename);
        try (
            final InputStream in = input;
        ) {
            Files.copy(in, destination,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }


        // ************* This one works but not for all(Sometimes creats a file with 0 bytes) ****************

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
        int aByte;
        while ((aByte = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(aByte);
        }
        bos.flush();
        fos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
        bis.close();

        ........
}
```

Comment: takunnithan do you want to add new file to zip file ?

Comment: @pudaykiran No, I extract it after copying.

Comment: Are you aware that Java's [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method already does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most of your ways damage the file because of you read InputStream to a String variable (binary files will be damaged). Try this implementation:

```
byte[] aByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
IOUtils.write(aByte, fos);
```

or

```
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
IOUtils.copy(input, fos);
```